# Is $x^n$ for some $0<x<1$ negligible?

Tags: calculus

A negligible function is a function that goes faster towards zero than the inverse of any polynomial (when the variable goes to infinity). For example $g(n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$ is a negligible function.

Is it in general true that $f(n) = x^n$ for some $0<x<1$ a negligible function? Note that x is a constant and n is the variable here.

If not, is $h(n) = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ a negligible function? How would I show that?

Comment: No polynomial tends to zero, so every function which does is negligible.

Comment: The function should go to zero when _what_ happens to $x$? Or is it something that happens to $n$ rather than $x$?

Comment: $h(n)=g(n)$ when $x=4/3$. And $g(n)$ is not negligible for $-1<x<1$.

Comment: BTW, It is really important to be clear. "A negligible function is a function $f(n)$ such that..." Make clear that $x$ is not input of the function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I edited the question to be more clear (and correct).

Comment: The $g(n)$ you gave is already of the form $x^n$ for $x=1/2$.

Comment: Oh wait, are you asking if $x^n$ is negligible *for all* $x$ in that range? "For some" confused me.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the function as

$$f(n) = e^{-n \log{(1/x)}}$$

As a function of $n$, because $\log{(1/x)} \gt 0$, $f$ decreases faster than any inverse polynomial as $n \to \infty$. Thus, according to your definition, $f(n)$ is "negligible."

Comment: How did you get $f(n) = e^{-n \log{(1/x)}}$? I see how I get $f(n) = e^{n \log{x}}$, but how do I get from here to your formula?

Comment: $$\log{(1/x)} = -\log{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is negligible. To show that $f\left(n\right)$ goes to zero faster than the inverse of any polynomial in $n$, just show that the ratio $f\left(n\right)/q\left(n\right)$ goes to zero, where $q$ is the inverse of a polynomial:

$$\left|\frac {f\left(n\right)} {q\left(n\right)}\right| = {x^n}\cdot\left| {a_d n^d + a_{d-1} n^{d-1} + \cdots}\right| =
\left|a_d\right| \cdot {x^n}{n^d}\cdot \left|{1+a_{d-1}n^{-1}/a_d+a_{d-2}n^{-2}/a_d+\cdots}\right|
$$
If you can show that $x^n n^d$ goes to zero as $n\to\infty$, with $d$ fixed, then you have shown that $f\left(n\right)$ is negligible in your definition. You also need to show that the quantity at the right goes to $1$, but that should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Standard argument: Let $d=\deg p$ be the degree of the polynomial, set $|x|=1/(1+a)$, then for $n>d$
$$
|p(n)x^n|\le \frac{|p(n)|}{1+\binom{n}{d+1}a^{d+1}}\sim\frac1n
$$
where the denominator has one degree more than the numerator and thus the bound converges to zero.